как сделать такие команды в описании бота в дискорд, при использовании disnake?
как сделать такие команды в описании бота в дискорд, при использовании disnake ? 

Никак. Они добавляются сами, как только бот станет верифицированным.
В списке команд может отображаться максимум до 5 самых использованных слэш команд (Если, таковые имеются в принципе).
Стоит также знать, что эти команды никак нельзя менять (пока крайней мере сейчас точно).
Источник: How do I add the "TRY MY COMMANDS" feature to my bot?
